# AC voltage b/w DC power supply o/p and Ground

Tags: electrical-engineering, pid-control, power-electronics, instrumentation, electronic-filters

I have various Phoenix Contact Mini DC Power supply units (Pheonix Contact MINI-PS-100-240AC-5DC). It gives the correct DC Voltage across output terminals, as its supposed to. But I also noticed that its also showing an AC Voltage of around 70 - 80 V between the O/P terminals and Ground as well as Neutral.

Is this normal?

I am using this power supply to use in combination with a relay, to serve as a Digital signal (5 VDC) source for monitoring status of certain devices in a system. I am using a National Instruments DAQ+modules and am worried that this AC voltage might damage the DAQ and modules(which are grounded through the DAQ chassis) which are extremely expensive.

Kindly explain if this a fault with my DC Power supply or if its normal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like [Phoenix Contact](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us?1dmy&urile=wcm%3apath%3a/usen/web/home) has many power supplies in their portfolio. Can you please share the model and the O/P voltage from the power supply. Example are you using 6VDC, 12VDC etc.

Comment: It is a 5VDC DIN rail Mountable MINI Power supply ---- Model Number Pheonix Contact MINI-PS-100-240AC-5DC.

Comment: Sounds like a grounding issue.

Comment: The Power supply has only a Line & Neutral port (no GRND) on the I/P side. Is this the cause? Or is it a fault with the wiring of our building?    Is there a way to avoid this , so that AC current may not flow through the DAQ?

Comment: When you respond to a person use @personsname? Otherwise this becomes just a comment.

Comment: What @StainlessSteelRat, is stating the DC GND. It is a good idea to isolate the AC GND from DC GND. **Question: ** Do you have separate AC GND and DC GND in the test rack?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the technical data there should not be a 70-80V AC signal in the output terminal. Either you are measuring incorrectly, a wiring issue, grounding issue or defective device.

Per the technical data there could be a 40mVpp residual ripple. If this is an issue I suggest applying a filter to pass only the DC components. Below is the high level block diagram for the power supply.

[image]

Here is the Output specification for the power supply.

[image: Power supply Output data]

Additional technical data can be found at [Power supply unit - MINI-PS-100-240AC/ 5DC/3 - 2938714](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=2938714&library=usen&tab=1#Outputdata)

Comment: Thank you for the info.